# How to create 3/4 face angle on a cartoon character?

Tags: drawing

It's me.
I want some advice on how to create a side angle easily. If you have the front face ready.
I created a character recently and was only able to create his front face, I am having trouble in making his side face.

This is where I am starting from with the image and the angle:
[image: Side Face (I want to create)]

Here is the front face I have been working on:

[image]

Can someone roughly give advice how it should look from a side view?

I would be happy. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to A&C Pro Co!

Comment: When it comes to a turned face. (I probably could put this as an answer) But understanding the human face helps significantly. The more you study the anatomy of the human face. The easier it will become.

Comment: @Lyssagal Love you Hi, thanks for all this, I am in love with you. thanks for the help. Thannks for the answer and sorry for I could not respond. But now! thanks

Comment: @Lyssagal The Editing of the Question you did is IDK awesome. and beautiful I love it and I am Enjoying in the Arts and Crafts community.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing the human face in a front view and trying to turn it in a way to make it a side view would be kind of difficult to achieve without erasing and mostly starting over. Because the human face shape changes when the face is turned away. Such as the direction of the nose, and overall shape of the face.

Example below are faces in different angles: pointed up, down, 3/4, and profile. By looking at these images you are able to tell how different the face structure changes when the head is turned. It will give some ideas of how to draw a character in a 3/4 view.

Studying the anatomy of the human face, the bone structure, the muscle structure would be a good benefit.

[image]

Took your image, and tried to draw it in a similar style related to the original front facing drawing. (Drawing with mouse so, I apologize) The face is going to have to turn and adjust so that the right side(our viewing side) will be the farthest away from the viewer. To make it look like the person face is turned.
[image]